# Django admin: how to increase field label width in admin change form view?

Tags: django, customization, admin

I want to customize Django admin change_form.html template for some of my model.
I would like to increase field label size and try by ovverriding change_form.html template.
But it dosen't work.

My own change_form.html is displayed but css style is not applied .

When I open debug, an error is raised for change_form.js: `django is not defined`

change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <!-- Custom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ecrf/css/custom_change_form.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

custom_change_form.css

```
// pat is one of my field
.column-pat {
    color: red !important;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

admin.py

```
class VisiteAdmin(SimpleHistoryAdmin):

    list_display = ('pat','vis_dat',timing_visit,'sai_log','sai_dat','ver','ver_usr','ver_dat')
    change_form_template = 'ecrf/admin/change_form.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `block.super`:

```
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
...

{% endblock %}
```